# How to invoke the register method as an inner class to create a pannel

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I'm trying to create a inner-class for creating a panel within a bigger class.. I'm working on a script that build menus and I'm trying to make a class that has a function where you can feed the name and it will create the menu.

```
import bpy


class BlenderCustomMenu(): 
    def __init__(self, software='blender', type_='pannels'):
        self.inner = self.Inner()  

    def createMenu():
        self.HelloWorldPanel.register 



    class Inner(bpy.types.Panel):
        """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
        bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
        bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
        bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
        bl_region_type = 'UI'
        bl_category = 'G1'

        def draw(self, context):
            layout = self.layout

            obj = context.object

            row = layout.row()
            row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

            row = layout.row()
            row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
            row = layout.row()
            row.prop(obj, "name")

            row = layout.row()
            row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")


        def register():
            bpy.utils.register_class(Inner)


        def unregister():
            bpy.utils.unregister_class(Inner)


#        if __name__ == "__main__":
#            register()




menu = BlenderCustomMenu()

menu.createMenu()
```